# Gaussian Error propagation on Transverse Momentum Measurement

Tags: error-analysis

Given the formula $$p_{T} = \frac{\left\vert q\right\vert B}{\kappa},$$
where $\left\vert q\right\vert$ denotes the modulus of the charge of a particle, $p_{T}$ its transverse momentum, $B$ the applied magnetic field and $\kappa$ the curvature in the transverse plane, I would like to understand how to arrive at $$\sigma_{p_{T}} = \frac{p_{T}^{2}}{\left\vert q\right\vert B}\sigma_{\kappa},$$ which I found in a textbook.

Comment: You find the general formula (method) by using the search bar and "error propagation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the relative uncertainty of transverse momentum, which you can show is equal to:
$$\frac{\sigma_{p_\text{T}}}{p_\text{T}}=\frac{\sigma_\kappa}{\kappa}$$
Substituting $\frac{1}{\kappa}=\frac{p_\text{T}}{|q|B}$ and rearranging:
$$\sigma_{p_\text{T}}=\frac{p_\text{T}^2}{|q|B}\sigma_\kappa$$